# Get the child of an HTML element by its XPath

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I have a really simple ask, i have a div in a html page that i can acces by his XPath which is : `//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]`.

I want a XPath that would give all the child of this div but i can't find it.
I need to get the element with the findElements method of Selenium, but what i've tested does not work:

My HTML code looks like this :

```
<div>
    <input/>
    <span/>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

And the XPath I want to use like this :

```
//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/child
```

And my Java Selenium script like this :

```
List<WebElement> listElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));

for(WebElement element : listElement) {
    System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

What XPath should I put to get the child of the `div`?

EDIT 1: I did use the * and it's working, but when i count the number of element it prints me 6. Does the * consider the children of his children as his own children ??

Comment: `//path/to/element/*` - the `/*` at the end selects all immediate children of `element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `div` in the HTML fragment in your question is located at

```
//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]
```

then the `input` child element would be here:

```
//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input
```

and all of the children elements would be here:

```
//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/*
```

---

**Update:**

> EDIT 1: I did use the * and it's working, but when i count the number
>   of element it prints me 6. Does the * consider the children of his
>   children as his own children ??

No, `div/*` selects only the immediate children elements of the parent `div`.

If you're being surprised by a greater number of children than expected, it may be that the base XPath is selecting multiple elements, and you're then selecting the children of more than just the targeted `div` element.

---

**Update 2:**

If you cannot post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and you're still puzzled about the number of children returned by,

```
//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/*
```

try challenging yourself on the XPath you've provided as the base:

```
//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/
```

First, try

```
//div[2]
```

Does it really select the single `div` as you expect?

Then try

```
//div[2]/div
```

Again, see if this one really selects the single `div` you expect.

Continue in this manner until you get to a place where the reality of the selected elements deviates from your expectations.  There your answer will be obvious, or your have a more specific question to ask.

Without seeing your XML/HTML, this is about as good as the advice can get.

Comment: But how can xpath as //div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2] point toward multiple element ?

Comment: For one, the second `div` in your XPath is without an index.   But, really, you should post an [mcve]; there are probably better ways to create a more robust XPath than what you've provided.

Comment: The project i'm working on is really shitty because they wanted o make something "dynamic" and "generic" but in the end it's only a big mess, their is no constant id and i can't use the css tag to isolate the different element... If i could provide the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable exemple i would.

Comment: Answer updated to provide you with a general XPath diagnostic technique.

Comment: Use the XPath `//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/*` and then in your loop print `element.getAttribute("outerHTML")`. That should point you to all the different elements that are being found using this XPath. Figure out which one(s) you don't want and update the XPath to exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> childs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/*"));
```

In that case selenium searchs for all child elements from path `div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/` and set them in list collection as `WebElement` object.

Comment: Code only answers are strongly discouraged. Please explain what your code does and how it answers the question.